# How to deal with QGIS Viewshed analysis MemoryError?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I have one SRTM Dem file and one point on it. I'm trying to use the Viewshed Analysis plugin for QGis to calculate the viewsheds from that point. Instead, I get this kind of error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Bogo/.qgis2/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\viewshedanalysis.py", line 194, in run
z_obs_field, z_target_field, curv, refraction)
File "C:/Users/Bogo/.qgis2/python/plugins\ViewshedAnalysis\doViewshed.py", line 496, in Viewshed
mx_dist = numpy.sqrt(temp_x[:,None] + temp_y[None,:])
MemoryError
```

I searched everywhere for a solution and I even installed the latest version of QGis, but with no luck.

Any help/ideas on what should I do to fix this? By they way, which version of QGis is the most stable according to you and which one doesn't have problems with plugins from the Processing Box?